# Onclick/Javascript for div; Rails iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a directory page where the listings are rendered on the index page.

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  # do some stuff
<% end %>
```

I've added a data-toggle to each listing - basically a button.

```
 <a id="chat-menu-toggle" href="#dr" class="chat-menu-toggle" >
   <div class="iconset top-chat-dark ">
      <span class="badge badge-important hide" id="chat-message-count">1
      </span>
   </div>                 
  </a>
```

This data-toggle opens a STATIC div. The div is a slider with content.

```
<div id="dr" class="chat-window-wrapper">
```

I want to use each button to pass the listing.id to a variable. Then, I can use that ID throughout the div.

For example:

**Listing with ID:**

- Stack - 1
- Overflow -2
- Ruby - 3
- Rails - 4
- Onclick - 5

Let's say I click the button for "Ruby" which has an id of 3, I want the id to be passed around like so.

```
 variable = 3

 <div id= <%= variable %> class="chat-window-wrapper">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure what you mean by "use that ID throughout the div." but you could try this if it helps you?

```
<div data-id="<%=listing.id %>" class="chat-window-wrapper">
```

If you want to get the id's value from what ruby printed then you can try adding an event listener

```
$(".chat-window-wrapper").on("click",function() { 
    var x = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id');
}
```

To access listings outside iterator try

```
listings[index]
```

or

```
@allListings = listings. Then access @allListings[index]
```

but as far as my rusty ruby knowledge goes, i think listings should be accessible as long as the controller is passing it in the context to the view.

Comment: It's less likely that `listing.id` could be duplicate, so keeping `id` is probably better for DOM querying.  I thought the problem is just the quotes around the `id`'s value which you've shown. +1

Comment: "use that ID throughout the div." => what I mean is, if I can grab that ID as a variable. I can use it in rails queries. ie. Thing.find(variable)

Comment: @miler350, how do you plan to execute `Thing.find(variable)`?  Is there any ajax call on that click event?

Comment: No, but there probably needs to be. I'm a novice at js.

This is how it currently works -- when you click the button, the main content div shifts left ~300px and makes an additional page column. I want to make the content of that column dynamic.

The issue is that the div code is outside of the iterator, so I need to grab the id from the iterator, and use it elsewhere on the page.

Comment: @user3413046 - I need access to the listing id outside of the iterator.