# Like/Unlike using acts_as_votable gem and ajax for nested resources on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, acts-as-votable

I realise that there are several similar questions, but none of them seem to address the issue with nested resources. I'm quite new to ROR and I am trying to implement a like/unlike using ajax with the [acts_as_votable gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable). I kind of understand how ajax works in Rails but I seem to have problems implementing it on my own.

**The structure**

My app has a list of Qs which each has a list of As. Users can 'bookmark/un-bookmark' a question or 'like/unlike' an answer. 'Downvoting' an answer like in stackoverflow is not permitted - users may only 'undo' their cast votes.

**Current Attempts**

This is the like snippet of my show.html.erb for a *Question*. It's not a separate partial file. It's within the show view.:

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
*omit*
<% if current_user.id!=answer.user_id %>
  <div class="heart-like">
    <br>
    <!-- Like Button -->

    <% if current_user.liked? answer %>
      <%= link_to unvote_question_answer_path(@question, answer), id: “like_#{answer.id}”, remote: :true do %>
        <span class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></span>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to like_question_answer_path(@question, answer), id: “like_#{answer.id}”, remote: :true do %>
        <span class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My routes:

```
resources :questions do
  member do
    get "bookmark"
  end
  resources :answers do
    member do
        put "like", to: "answers#upvote"
        put "unvote", to: "answers#unvote"
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

My answers controller has these two methods:

```
def upvote
  begin
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    @answer.liked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :nothing => true, :status => 404
  end
end

# undo prev vote
def unvote
  begin
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    @answer.unliked_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the js I made with tremendous help from [this blog](https://medium.com/@albychen5/liking-unliking-w-ajax-and-acts-as-votable-gem-6ce440af9b16), which I don't know where to put:

```
$(“#like_<%= @answer.id %>”).removeClass(‘fa fa-heart-o’).addClass(‘fa fa-heart’);
$(“#like_<%= @answer.id %>”).attr(“href”, ‘/answers/<%= @answer.id %>/unlike’);
$(“#likes_<%= @answer.id %>”).html(“<%= j (render partial: ‘answers/likes’, locals: {answer: @answer} ) %>”);
```

=> BUT I think everything should be @question.answer.id, because the answers are nested within the questions -> which I am completely confused over. But if I use @question.answer.id, what should {answer: @answer} this part look like?

And the partial is (_likes.html.erb)

```
<div class="num-votes">
  <%= answer.votes_for.size %> Likes
</div>
```

So I'm confused about a few things:

1. Where does _likes.html.erb and like.js.erb go in my project dir (in answers? in questions?)
2. How do I write my like.js.erb file when the answers are nested (made a few attempts but all failed :( )

And how can I get this to work? (currently the like doesn't do anything... and the heart isn't displayed as well.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your js should be in a template like an html.erb but js.erb. So this js

```
$("#like_<%= @answer.id %>").removeClass('fa fa-heart-o').addClass('fa fa-heart');
$("#like_<%= @answer.id %>").attr("href", '/answers/<%= @answer.id %>/unlike');
$("#likes_<%= @answer.id %>").html("<%= j (render partial: 'answers/likes', locals: {answer: @answer} ) %>");
```

Should be in "views/answers/upvote.js.erb" but I'm not sure but if you update your post with your routes with command 'rails routes', you'll have a response

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not getting the right id when iterating, instead always using @answer.id on javascript file.

This might help a little:

[Onclick/Javascript for div; Rails iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365833/onclick-javascript-for-div-rails-iterator)